# What's so different about token-based authentication?

Tags: authentication, token

Many articles I have read online about token-based authentication seem to imply that token-based authentication is different than "traditional" authentication systems partly because token-based authentication "relies on a signed token that is sent to the server on each request." How is this any different than the way the session ID is sent to the server on each request in traditional authentication systems?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a generic security question. It seems more appropriate for [security.se] instead (where it may already have been answered).

Answer (score 1):

A session ID is typically a random key into a database of sessions that are stored on the server. The "database" doesn't have to be a RDBM, but some storage thing. When a request comes in with a session ID, the server needs to look up the session ID to find the session. If there isn't server affinity, looking up the session may involve a remote call.

With token authentication, there doesn't need to be a server-side session. Instead, information such as the user's name is stored in the token and passed directly from the client. If done with cyrptography, this would lead to security vulnerabilities. But the token is signed by a secret that is only known to the server. So the server can recalculate the signature and verify that the token is legitimate.

The information in the token can be extended to include more and more information from the session, perhaps removing the need for a server-side session altogether.

There are some references available such as [this one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication).

Comment: one of the best and simplest explainations I've ever seen about token based authentication  - ty!